# Moving towards the center of rotation svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I am facing a problem with svg on my portfolio page.
I have created svg and I used animation to spin the svg in infinite loop. Problem occures when I reload my portfolio page multiple times. When I do, my screen starts to move towards the center of spinning. I am looking for fix, anyone knows what might help?

images:

[image]

after few reloads:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;  
  background-color: var(--color-tertiary);
  overflow-x: hidden; // My svg is really big and it overflows page, so I need to use this
}

/***************** HEADER **********************/

.header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative; 

  &__logo{ // this is the svg 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30rem;
    width: 180rem;
    z-index: -1; // I use z-index to make sure that moving svg is in the background of the page

    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 500s linear infinite;
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);} }
  }

  &__wrapper{
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this issue can be properly diagnosed without a [mcve].  Please create a standalone working example (a JSFiddle or similar) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I see that this part:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);} }
```

is inside of the class. All keyframes should be standalone. In the @keyframes line also remove -webkit- from transform.